# Voltage across different power sources and transformers

Tags: voltage, electronics

Something cause a potential difference between the two poles of a power source. The same kind of 'something' of two different power sources may also cause a voltage between those two different power sources as shown in the schematics below.

But what will the voltmeter at the bottom of the schematics below show? 100V as well like the top one or does the transformers somehow remove that "special something" that cause the 100V on the top?

[image: schematics]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the context, I assume that all the voltages shown on your diagram are AC voltages.

If so, we can imaging that there is some AC source connected in parallel with the top voltmeter. Since the transformers have some parasitic capacitance between their primaries and secondaries, we can replace them by a couple of capacitors.

[image]

Looking at this equivalent circuit, we can see that the voltage on the voltmeter at the bottom will be a fraction of the voltage on the top. The exact measured voltage will depend on the impedance of the source, impedance of the parasitic capacitors and the impedance of the bottom voltmeter, at the AC frequency.

Since voltmeters tend to have high impedance, chances are the measured voltage will be a significant fraction of the voltage at the top.

Comment: Agreed, but without the parasitic capacitance, the 'special something' would be removed, as in an ideal transformer the coupling between the windings is by means of alternating magnetic fields, and these carry no information about primary voltages except insofar as they drive the currents through the primary coils that produce the magnetic fields!

Comment: So the two magnetic fields carries in no way information about if or what's causing the 100V on the top meter? IF the top meter measures 100V because the right power source compared to the left power source have a much higher concentration of electrons (in whole circuit) and needs that to chemically produce 5V internally, then is that circumstance (higher concentration of electrons) in any way affecting the magnetic field in the transformer in such a way that the right transformer induce something that differs from the left transformer in such a way that the bottom meter is affected by that?

Comment: @Theflyingcanofsoup Your circuit does not contain enough information to determine what is causing $100$V on the top (ideally there should not be any), so all I can say is that, if you measure $100$V there, you'll see some voltage at the bottom as well, which I thought was the answer to your question.